# How to change the T4 (Context.tt) to show classes and properties in CamelCase?

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I am completely new to T4 templates. I need to create entities and their properties in CamelCase--instead of the default lowercase--for EntityFramework 6.0.

Where and what changes do I need to make to the Context.tt (T4) file to accomplish this?

Thanks much for any help.

Edit#1
The database names and properties are coming from unquoted names in a PostgreSQL (9.5) database. By default, PostgreSQL is case-insensitive and the names are returned in lowercase. To match the code from a previous domain model, I need the first letter of the database tables and property names to be uppercase--the rest of the letters lowercase.

Comment: There is no default lower case. What do the database names look like?

Comment: @GertArnold The database names and properties are coming from unquoted names in a PostgreSQL (9.5) database. By default, PostgreSQL is case-insensitive and the names are returned in lowercase. To match the code from a previous domain model, I need the first letter of the database and property names to be uppercase--the rest of the letters lowercase.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I solved this problem. Please see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468335/how-to-write-a-t4-template-to-create-dtos-from-entityframework-6